# The column order is broken when I attempt to convert dataframe into excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

everyone, I've encountered some problems when I user panda.dataframework to display data and save to excel file:

My goal is save dataframe to excel file, my code is following:

```
data_final = {'Case index':ranked_index,
          'Similarity':prob_list,
          'Case description':content_info}
frame = pandas.DataFrame(data_final)
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(rooter + '\\Final_Score_Result.xlsx')
frame.to_excel(writer, 'Results', index = False)
writer.save()
```

And the results is as follows:
[image]

But I want to keep the column order as same as I provide in dictionary: like this:

[image]

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem???

Comment: before using writer, add this line - frame = frame[['Case index', 'Similarity', 'Case description']]. this will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need define order in `DataFrame` constructor, because dict under `python 3.6` are not orderable:

```
frame = pandas.DataFrame(data_final, columns=['Case index','Similarity', 'Case description'])

writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(rooter + '\\Final_Score_Result.xlsx')
frame.to_excel(writer, 'Results', index = False)
writer.save()
```

**Sample**:

```
data_final = {'Case index':[1,2,3],
          'Similarity':[6,7,8],
          'Case description':['asa','def','gth']}

frame = pandas.DataFrame(data_final, columns=['Case index','Similarity', 'Case description'])
print (frame)
   Case index  Similarity Case description
0           1           6              asa
1           2           7              def
2           3           8              gth
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, use an OrderedDict :

```
import collections

data_final = collections.OrderedDict([('Case index',ranked_index),
      ('Similarity',prob_list),
      ('Case description',content_info)])
frame = pandas.DataFrame(data_final)
```

If you are only using pandas to be your Excel writer, another way to skin the chicken is use `csv.DictWriter()` instead of `pandas`.

Answer (score 0):

While writing dataframe to excel use `columns` arguments and pass the sequence.

```
frame.to_excel(writer, 'Results', index = False,
               columns=['Case index','Similarity', 'Case description'])
```